# DependencyProperty in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm creating a UserControl "UC". I have my class with data "AClass". I want an object of this class to be a DP in my UserControl. So i put the definition in UC:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(AClass),
    typeof(UC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new AClass()));

public AClass A
{
    get { return (AClass)GetValue(AProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
}
```

Here's how I create my control in XAML:

```
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MyWorkspace"
// ...
<Grid>
    <l:UC Height="100" Width="150" Activity="{Binding a}" />
</Grid>
```

I defined "a" in the code-behind file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public AClass a {get; set;}
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        a = // create an object
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Next, in my UC I want to refer to "A" and use one of its property:

```
private void DoSomethingInUC()
{
   int size = A.AsProperty;
   // ...
}
```

The problem is that every time I refer to "A" it is uninitialized (i.e. "AsProperty" contains default value).

What's wrong in that ?

Comment: In your XAML, you are not binding property `A`, but `Activity` instead. Intentional?

Answer (score 0):

1) How can your A DP be of type double *and* AClass?

2) You most likely want to avoid doing this :

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new AClass())
```

because the exact AClass instance you new up right there will be shared
  as default by all of your UserControl instances.

3) You have to make your MainWindow implement INotifyPropertyChanged (prefer making
a MainWindowViewModel) and have your a property RaisePropertyChanged inside it's setter.

Comment: 1) Ooopps, sorry - I modified the code a bit to make it more readable and made this mistake - thanks.
2.) Can I ignore the forth argument in "Register" at all ?
3.) I'll give it a try and let you know soon about the results.